# r subset and subtract one column from other columns in a data.frame

Tags: r, function

I'm wondering if someone might be able to help me with writing a function to do this. I have a dataframe that looks like of like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(TestA1 = c(1,2), TestA2 = c(2,3), TestB1 = c(3,4), TestB2 = c(5,6), A = c(1,1), B = c(2,2))
df
TestA1 TestA2 TestB1 TestB2 A B
1      2      3      5 1 2
2      3      4      6 1 2
```

I want to subtract the "A" column from all the other columns that have A in the name (ie TestA1 and TestA2), and do the same for the B and its matching columns. Is this too much to try and do in one function?

I'm still new to R and I've been doing this manipulation piece by piece on my dataset and it seems very inefficient (full data set is 25000x55). I've been trying to wrap my head around how to write a function to do it and have been really struggling. Any help/guidance would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

Ideally the output be (if selecting for B)

```
NewTestB1  NewTestB2
1          3
2          4
```

So B = c(2,2) would have been subtracted from each column that it matched resulting in an output dataframe consisting of the columns that had been selected for and the additional adjustment.

Comment: Is it possible for a column to be both A and B? Are you saying you don't know the column names in advance and have to search for matches?

Comment: no it's not possible for columns to be both. I know the column names in advance I was just hoping to be able to write it so that I could match the column that needs to be subtracted from the others as matching a component of the name with out separating into several smaller data frames

Comment: Get the names with names(), then grepl() for A and B to get the names.  Then do the subtraction Avars - A   .

Comment: according to the above: library(dplyr)
df %>% select(grep("A", names(df)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, providing the function that you want:

```
myF <- function( object, selector )
{
    ix <- which( grepl( selector, colnames( object ) ) & colnames( object ) != selector )
    rowSums( object[ ix ] ) - object[ selector ]
}
```

So the call

```
myF( df, "B" )
```

would give you

```
  B
1 6
2 8
```

This is based upon your certainly simplified sample and probably needs some adaption. You may also want to rename the  data.frame that is returned, but that all depends upon your further use of the result.

If you want to have a vector in return, rather than a one column data.frame, change to

```
rowSums( object[ ix ] ) - object[ selector ][ , 1 ]
```

EDIT:

This is probably what you want:

```
myF <- function( object, selector )
{
    ix <- which( grepl( selector, colnames( object ) ) & colnames( object ) != selector )
    for( i in ix )
        object[ length( object ) + 1 ] <- object[ i ] - object[ selector ]
    return( object )
}
```

This gives you

```
myF( df, "B" )
  TestA1 TestA2 TestB1 TestB2 A B TestB1.1 TestB2.1
1      1      2      3      5 1 2        1        3
2      2      3      4      6 1 2        2        4
```

Some improvements like better column names etc might be done but the functionality is achieved. Also, be aware that this does not change the original data.frame but provides you with an updated copy.

2nd EDIT, removing the columns:

```
myF <- function( object, selector )
{
    ix <- which( grepl( selector, colnames( object ) ) & colnames( object ) != selector )
    for( i in ix )
        object[ length( object ) + 1 ] <- object[ i ] - object[ selector ]
    object <- object[ -ix ]
    object <- object[ -(which( colnames( object ) == selector ) ) ]
    return( object )
}
```

producing

```
myF( df, "B" )
  TestA1 TestA2 A TestB1.1 TestB2.1
1      1      2 1        1        3
2      2      3 1        2        4
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! I was trying to make some tweaks to it, cause I actually need each TestB column to separately have B subtracted from it, and the output would be the data.frame of all the new/adjusted TestB's. I took out the rowSums to make it just object[ix] - object[selector] but I'm getting the error that "-" only works for equally sized data frames. How would I write it so that the subtraction is applied to each column?

Comment: You mean subtracting B from TestB1, creating a column with the value, and then subtract B from TestB2, creating another column with that value?

Comment: yes so the output would be a 2x2 dataframe with the new values of TestB1 and TestB2 having had B subtracted from them 

(can't figure out how to make an example of that in the comments but I'll add it to the original post)

Comment: I think this would be a situation where a for loop would be helpful.... ie for each column in the object[ix] - object[selector].... but still getting the hang of for loops, so not totally sure

Comment: yes thank you! that's more like what i'm looking for.
can I ask what exactly the "object[ length(object) + 1]" part is doing? 
and if it would be possible for the returned output to not include the original columns?

Comment: `object[ length(object) + 1]` adds another column at the end of the data.frame. I did not want to hard code the number of cols. And which cols of the original data.frame you want to drop exactly?

Comment: ah got it. So it adds another column and those added columns are the object[i]-object[selector]. The cols I'd want to drop are all the unadjusted columns, such that the output would only be the B1.1 and B2.1.

Comment: When you use the function, you might want to assign the return value to your existing data.frame: `df <- myF( df, "B" )`.